# Is it possible to specify a file conforms to a specific type / interface in TypeScript?

Tags: node.js, typescript, types, export

I've been playing around with some different styles in TypeScript and I really enjoy the `import * as User from './user'` syntax from node, I was wondering if it is possible to specify a default type as well. Let's say I have an interface like this I want each file to implement:

```
interface PersistantData<T> {

   load(): Promise<T>

   save(): Promise<boolean>
}
```

the I have another file **preferences.ts**

```
export let locale: string = 'en' 

export let theme: 'light' | 'dark' = 'light'

export async function save() {
   // handle save
}

export async function load() {
   // handle loading
}

type Settings = PersistantData<{
    locale: string
    theme: 'light' | 'dark'
}>

export (default as Settings) // this doesn't work
```

this way another file **storage.ts** can do the following:

```
import type { PersistantData } from './types'
import * as settings from './settings'
import * as user from './user'

const itemsToPersist: PersistantData<any> = [settings, user]

export async function saveToDisk() {
   await Promise.all(itemsToPersist.map(item => item.save()))
}
```

I know I can do the type-casting in the storage implementation, but it would be nice to have the compiler tell me if I forgot to implement a property or method?

- Specify a type that can be used with `import * as ...`
- Ideally have that type also in the file that exports

I know there are other ways to do this, but just wondering if something like this is possible?

Answer (score 0):

I did find a somewhat *hacky* way to achieve this effect in the file **settings.ts**

```
// import from self!
import * as Settings from './settings'

// type definitions
interface Persistable {
  save(): Promise<boolean>;
  load(): Promise<boolean>;
}

export type PersistableSettings = Persistable & {
  locale: string;
  theme: 'light' | 'dark';
}

// implementation
export let locale: string = "en";
export let theme: 'light' | 'dark' = "light";

export async function save() {
  return true
}

export async function load() {
  return true
}

// export magic
export const settings: PersistableSettings = Settings;
// or
export default settings
```

now in another file it works!

[image: import example]